# Why does C# Parallel.ForEach throw IndexOutOfBounds and foreach does not?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I made this small program to test parallelization.

When I hit button1 several times it ends up with an IndexOutOfBounds exception. I guess this is because I run out of memory. Why do I get this with parallelization and not with a regular foreach(button2 click)?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    int[] nums = new int[10000];
    List<int> randoms = new List<int>();

    Parallel.ForEach(nums, i =>
    {
        randoms.Add(new Random().Next());
    });

    s.Stop();
    label1.Text = "Added " + randoms.Count() + " randoms in "
                  + s.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    int[] nums = new int[10000];
    List<int> randoms = new List<int>();
    foreach (var i in nums)
    {
        randoms.Add(new Random().Next());
    }

    s.Stop();
    label2.Text = "Added " + randoms.Count() + " randoms in "
                  + s.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying `randoms` in parallel. That is a bug because the list is not safe for concurrent adding.

Also, IndexOutOfBounds has nothing to do with out-of-memory. You can find out all of this by looking carefully at the exception: The message tells you it is not OOM. And the stack trace tells you in which line the error occured (it was in the `Add`-line, right?).

Comment: I see. So i can not add to a list in the parallel? Is there an other way to do this? You are right about the exception. I dont know why i missread that.

Comment: @espvar you could use a lock. That would introduce crazy contention though, destroying all benefits. Look into PLINQ - it is good for producing values. (You also need to solve the problem with concurrent random number generation which has pitfalls in it - Google it).

Answer (score 2):

In your `Parallel.ForEach` code, you are concurrently modifying a `List<int>` which is not threadsafe.

The exception occurs when you try to add to the end of a `List` while the internal array is being resized in a different thread.

Instead you should use a concurrent collection like [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) or [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. That actually made me understand muuch more how parallel works differently from single threads.