# c# Parallel.ForEach throwing indexOutOfBoundException

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using a lot of `parallel foreach` loops. they are mostly used for elaborating datas and after add them to a list.

this is an example of my methods:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(magazzini, m =>
{
    try
    {
        warehouse.Add(new WAREHOUSE()
        {
            ID = m.Id,
            NAME = m.new_name,
            CODE = m.new_codice,
            INTEGRATION_KEY = m.dynamics_integrationkey,
            RESOURCE_ID = m.new_mobileuser == null ? Guid.Empty : m.new_mobileuser.Id
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.Error(authToken, string.Format("GetAllMagazzini|Magazzini|{0}", ex.InnerException));
    }
});
```

I read in [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763596/4700782) that it might be caused by the not thread-safe property of the `List<T>`. My problem is the following:

I have those not only for loops like this but also for long loops with a lot of operations. I had to use the `parallel.foreach` because using the classic `foreach` makes the query to timeout, since it's on a WebService.

How can I use the `parallel.foreach` avoiding the `indexOutOfBoundException`? I have to change the `List<T>` in something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change `List<T>` to [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since the resizing of the backing array in `List<T>` will cause problems with concurrent write operations. Another option is to create a `lock` around the add operation.

If there are no other operations that adding in your `Parallel.ForEach` concurrency is not necessary and will even negatively impact performance. If that is the case, create a regular `foreach` or use `AddRange`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! just a little question: why if there is only the add operation it will negatively impact performance? how to know if using parallel or non-parallel foreach?

Comment: You can't resize an array in parallel, you can't set a memory address in parallel. So that would be a no for concurrency. If you get the contents of a file, a web page, you can have multiple actions running next to each other, so that would allow concurrency.